# hciconfig command in python and rc.local will not work

Tags: bluez

I want set `hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0` at boot

I add this command to `/etc/rc.local` but `sspmode` is always Enable and when I execute command manually in terminal working like a charm.

I execute command with python `os.system('sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 0')` and again won't work.

Why?

how I change `hciconfig` default value?

I work on `raspbian` and `raspberry pi`

Comment: Can you add OS and version in your question?

Comment: @taliezin Added

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `subprocess` in the following manner.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['sudo hciconfig', 'hci0', 'sspmode', 0], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```